# When google drive API v2 stop supported

Tags: google-drive-api

As title, what is the https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files valid period? thanks.

Comment: Is anybody here ;)

Comment: If that answers your question, please accept. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you have existing apps based on Drive API v2 you can migrate to
>   Drive API v3. The differences between Drive API v3 and v2 are mainly
>   changes to field names and removal of duplicate functionality.

There is no definite cease date for Drive v2 stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration). You can still use Drive v2 methods but it is highly encouraged that you [Migrate to Google Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration). But for now, you can still use it.